# Get Previous Processed Document in MongoDb

Tags: database, mongodb, bigdata, aggregation

I have the following collection structure:

```
{
   "col1": "col1_value1",
   "col2": "col2_value1"
}

{
   "col1": "col1_value2",
   "col2": "col2_value2"
}
```

How do I get the following result in MongoDB:

```
  {
   "previous_col1": "", // init value
   "col1": "col1_value1",
   "previous_col2": "",
   "col2": "col2_value1"
  }

 {
  "previous_col1": "col1_value1",  // previous value
  "col1": "col1_value2",

  "previous_col2": "col2_value1",
  "col2": "col2_value2"
 }
```

In SQL, I can achieve the same result by defining two variables @previous_col1 and @previous_col2 for keeping previous rows.

Answer (score 0):

This *mongo shell* query does that:

```
var cur = db.collection.find();

var result_docs = [ ];
var prev_col1 = "", prev_col2 = "";

while (cur.hasNext()) {
    let thisDoc = cur.next();
    thisDoc.previous_col1 = prev_col1;
    thisDoc.previous_col2 = prev_col2;
    prev_col1 = thisDoc.col1;
    prev_col2 = thisDoc.col2;
    result_docs.push(thisDoc);
}
```

The `result_docs` array has all the documents updated with previous document's values.

Comment: Many thanks for your support. I got my expected result.